# Sci kit learn confusion matrix always look almost the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

So I'm pretty new to both Machine Learning and Python but have managed to be able to classify my data and print the confusion matrix with various classifiers with the code below:

```
def classify_data(df, feature_cols, file):
nbr_folds = 5
attributes = df.loc[:, feature_cols]  # Also known as x
class_label = df['task']  # Class label, also known as y.
file.write("\nFeatures used: ")
for feature in feature_cols:
    file.write(feature + ",")
print("Features used", feature_cols)

print("MLP")
file.write("MLP")
mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
class_label_predicted = cross_val_predict(mlp, attributes, class_label, cv=nbr_folds)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(class_label, class_label_predicted)
print(conf_mat)
accuracy = accuracy_score(class_label, class_label_predicted)
print("\nRows classified: " + str(len(class_label_predicted)))
print("\nAccuracy: {0:.3f}%\n".format(accuracy * 100))
file.write("\nClassifier settings:" + str(mlp) + "\n")
file.write("\nRows classified: " + str(len(class_label_predicted)))
file.write("\nAccuracy: {0:.3f}%\n".format(accuracy * 100))
file.writelines('\t'.join(str(j) for j in i) + '\n' for i in conf_mat)

print("RandomForest")
file.write("\nRandomForest")
#sv = svm.SVC(kernel="linear")
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
class_label_predicted = cross_val_predict(clf, attributes, class_label, cv=nbr_folds)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(class_label, class_label_predicted)
print(conf_mat)
accuracy = accuracy_score(class_label, class_label_predicted)
print("Rows classified: " + str(len(class_label_predicted)))
print("Accuracy: {0:.3f}%\n".format(accuracy * 100))
file.write("\nClassifier settings:" + str(clf) + "\n")
file.write("\nRows classified: " + str(len(class_label_predicted)))
file.write("\nAccuracy: {0:.3f}%\n".format(accuracy * 100))
file.writelines('\t'.join(str(j) for j in i) + '\n' for i in conf_mat)
```

However, I am starting to wonder if I am doing something wrong here as the confusion matrix is almost always the same, putting everything in on my fifth feature. When I run the exact same data set with the same attributes in the Weka application, I get different results. Below is an example:

```
sci kit learn:
MLP
Rows classified: 6881
Accuracy: 25.970%
0   0   0   0   412 12  0   0   25  1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   540 50  0   0   8   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   111 3   0   0   6   2   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   139 19  0   0   4   2   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1630    54  0   0   106 18  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   554 63  0   0   22  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   246 8   0   0   33  10  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   324 39  0   0   8   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   605 60  0   0   90  5   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   519 31  0   0   72  4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   455 19  0   0   10  1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   260 11  0   0   21  1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   236 8   0   0   21  3   0   0   0

RandomForest:
Rows classified: 6881
Accuracy: 26.174%
0   0   0   0   440 0   0   0   10  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   597 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   119 0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   164 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1774    0   0   0   34  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   629 0   0   0   10  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   268 0   0   0   29  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   371 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   733 0   0   0   27  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   605 0   0   0   21  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   484 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   286 0   0   0   7   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   263 0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0

Weka
MLP
    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k    l    m   <-- classified as
    5  504   50    1    0    0   10   28    0    0    0    0    0 |    a = t1
    2 1511   56    1    4    1   83  135    0    2   12    0    1 |    b = t12
    4  467   88    0    1    3   30   45    0    0    0    1    0 |    c = t2
    1  227   15    2    2    0   36   13    0    1    0    0    0 |    d = t3
    4  369   18    2    1    0   25   31    0    0    0    0    0 |    e = t0
    3  306   43    0    1    2   10    6    0    0    0    0    0 |    f = t4
    5  463   36    2    4    0  178   69    0    0    2    0    1 |    g = t5
    3  371   23    1    0    0   49  176    0    0    2    1    0 |    h = t6
    4  398   14    1    1    0   28   33    0    0    5    1    0 |    i = t7
    1  252   13    0    0    0   16    8    0    1    2    0    0 |    j = t8
    1  213    9    0    0    0   20   24    0    1    0    0    0 |    k = t9
    1   96    3    0    0    0    4   16    0    0    2    0    0 |    l = t10
    1  133    7    0    0    0    7   15    0    0    1    0    0 |    m = t11
```

**I also wonder if it possible to print the confusion matrix with the class labels as Weka is doing? Here it looks like column b is somewhat equal to the fifth column in sci kit learn but it is difficult to tell what column it represents.**

Comment: There is a wonderful package to deal with imbalanced classes: https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your data set is heavily **imbalanced** - 5th class is extremely dominant and your models simply learn to predict this label most of the time.

How to deal with this? Read for example [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/).

Comment: Ah, yes I have been looking for the correct term. I thought there should be some balancing functions in sci kit learn. I will look them up.